# why it gives a type parameter not within bound error

Tags: java

I have implemented a red-black tree(class RBTree), and I am trying to use the tree to implement a Map class(class RBMap).

```
public class RBTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node<T> root; // The root node of the tree

    public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {...}
}
```

My idea is first to implement a Pair class which takes a key and a value, and use this as nodes in the tree. But even if I implemented Comparable Interface, it still give an error as shown in picture.

```
public class RBMap<K,V> {

RBTree<Pair> _root; -> error: type parameter "RBMap.Pair" is not within its bound, should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<RBMap.Pair>'

public class Pair<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<Pair> {
    K key;
    V value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        return this.key.compareTo((K) o.key);
    }
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: You may need to share code as text instead of images and should share more details

Comment: Yes, please don't share text as screenshots.  Post your code, and results, including errors, as text.  Also, provide enough information that we can grab your code, put it in our own editor, and get the same result you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saw my earlier answer...sorry about that.  My IDE had included the import of Apache's Pair, so I was thinking you were overriding that somehow.  I then realized that you're defining your own Pair on its own.  So my answer was wrong.

I think the problem here is that you're trying to redefine the type parameters K and V.  You already have those defined by the outer class.  So the inner Pair class is already qualified by those because it's defined inside the outer class.  You definitely don't want to redefine the same parameters K and V.  You might want to define new parameters, like Y and Z, but I'm thinking that you want them all to be the same two types.  In that case, I think you just want:

```
class RBTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        T value;
    }
}

public class RBMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {

    RBTree<Pair> pair;

    public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
        K key;
        V value;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair o) {
            return this.key.compareTo((K) o.key);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not sure about not needing to qualify the types on Pair, think about what you'd do if you wanted to use this Pair definition in another class.  You'd do this:

```
    RBMap<Integer, Integer>.Pair _pair;
```

so even used independently outside the RBMap class, you've already provided the two types utilized in the Pair object.

Comment: The same applies to `Node` inside `RBTree`.